# Proving a binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ gives a semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, semigroups

Let $x\circ y= x +y-xy, \quad (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}$

where $\circ$ is a binary operation on $\mathbb{Z}$, prove that this is a semigroup.

**My Work**

To prove we have to check two things:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under $\circ$
- $\circ$ is associative on $\mathbb{Z}$

For the first one, since we are only adding, subtractive and multiplying integers, the results will always be integers. Hence $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under $\circ$.

For the second, I just have to show that $(x\circ y) \circ z =x\circ(y\circ z)$.

RHS: $(x\circ y) \circ z =(x+y-xy)\circ z= x+y-xy+z-zx-zy+xyz$

LHS: $x\circ(y\circ z)=x\circ (y+z-yz)=x +y-xy+z-zx-zy+xyz$

Hence RHS$=$LHS.

Therefore $(\mathbb{Z},\circ)$ is a semigroup.

> Is this correct? And is there a better way to show that it's closed?

Comment: Looks right to me. Usually these elementary algebra exercises are just plug-and-chug, nothing flashy about the proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This structure as @Cameron confirmed, defines a *infinite* semigroup $S$. $S$ has $0$ and $1$ as two idempotent elements, since $0*0=0$ and $1*1=1$ and so it is not a band. It seems that $S$ has $0$ as its identity $e$ i.e. for all $a\in S$, $a*e=e*a=a$. $S$ looks like a commutative semigroup, since $$x*y=y*x, \forall x,y\in\mathbb Z$$

Comment: Nice...nothing left for me to add! +1

Comment: $x \circ 0 = x$ for all $x$, please see my answer.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti: Yes! I lost it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is instructive to see how these exercises arise. This also gives a handy solution: once you have the general setup described below, there is really nothing to prove.

Consider the map $\varphi : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ given by $\varphi(x) = 1 - x$.

Note that $\varphi^{2} = \mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{Z}}$, so that $\varphi$ is bijective, and $$\varphi(x) \varphi(y) = (1 - x) (1 - y) = 1 - x - y + xy  = 1 - (x + y - xy) = \varphi(x \circ y),$$
so that
$$
x \circ y = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x) \varphi(y)).
$$
(Ok, I know $\varphi^{-1} = \varphi$ in this particular case.) So $(\Bbb{Z}, \circ)$ is obtained through [transport of structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) from $(\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)$,
and
$$
\varphi: (\Bbb{Z}, \circ) \to (\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)
$$
is an isomorphism. The structure of a monoid of $(\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)$ carries over to $(\Bbb{Z}, \circ)$ verbatim, you are really verifying the familiar axioms in $(\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)$, only indirectly via $\varphi$. In particular, the identity of $(\Bbb{Z}, \circ)$ is $\varphi^{-1}(1) = 0$, where $1$ is the identity of $(\Bbb{Z}, \cdot)$.

By the way, this *circle operation* ([or a slight variation thereof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_element)) plays an important role in the theory of the [Jacobson radical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical).

Comment: @BabakS., you're very welcome. It's just that once you get the isomorphism, things are so much easier to see.

Answer (score 2):

Your method of showing closure is pretty much as good as it gets, and your associativity proof is just fine.